# Android API for Zigbee connectivity

Tags: android, linux-kernel, device, linux-device-driver

Android has connectivity APIs like android.net.wifi and android.bluetooth

Is there a similar API for zigbee ? e.g. if I want the phone to be a zigbee end node

Assuming that I've already installed .ko module (driver) for zigbee in underlying Linux kernel

What should be done to access this module ? In other words, how various android APIs for device management are actually implemented ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you developing custom Android device with zigbee hardware and custom android?

Generally speaking the stack looks approximately like this (from bottom to top)

- Hardware
- Linux kernels + drivers
- JNI (Java Native Interface) talking to drivers
- Jave services using JNI. This services expose high level API to the device.
- Client side Java code, which is package in android.jar which is bundled into an app. This client side talks to Java services.

Answering your questions:

- Vanilla Android doesn't have API for zigbee (none of the layers mentioned before)
- If you want to support it, you will need to build a custom Android build which will include at least some of layers.

Comment: I know that I will have to build a custom Android build, what I'm asking is, what should I add/modify if I already have zigbee end node driver in the linux kernel layer ? by the way, as far as I understood, those "java services using JNI" correspond to "application framework" layer in this pic ?  http://ist-music.berlios.de/site/images/music-android-architecture.jpg

Comment: also, should I add wrapper functions for driver into native libraries (green layer in pic above) ? or maybe JNI is going to talk directly with driver, bypassing those libraries ?

Comment: 2mangusta: This architecture view which you posted is very popular, but it's not 100% accurate. It's missing a layer of services (both Java service, C++ services and JNI part). As soon as client side code calls some API in application framework layer, this call is send to some of the services through Binder (IPC mechanism) and a service will do some job. So, when I was talking about Java services and JNI, I was talking about components, which aren't shown in this pic. You can see examples of services in AOSP \frameworks\base\services (it has both java and jni part)

Comment: BTW. You may be interested to browse through this website - http://www.kandroid.org/ and check this book http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920021094.do
They may have information on adding new devices to Android.